# Want to make rotating button which I can press while animating

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've made a rotating button. But while button rotates I can't press it. So The question is how I can make it "pressable"?
My animation code is:

```
  var max: Bool = true

  func startAnimation() {

    max = !max
    let duration: Double = 1
    let fullCircle = 2 * M_PI


    let upOrDown = (max ? CGFloat(-1 / 16 * fullCircle) : CGFloat(1 / 16 * fullCircle))
    let scale: (CGFloat, CGFloat) = (max ? (1.0, 1.0) : (1.3, 1.3))

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in

      let rotationAnimation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(upOrDown)
      let scaleAnimation = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale)
      self.startButton.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotationAnimation, scaleAnimation)

      }) { (finished) -> Void in
        self.startAnimation()
    }
```

So if I press button there is no any effect that it has happened. No text inside button text animation - nothing! But button keep rotating and don't perform segue to other scene. But if it is no animation I can do segue.

Comment: What you mean by "not pressable" ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I can't press it. So I press but there is absolutely no effect. If animating is off I can go to other scene

Comment: You need to use the animation block method with options and set the option for user interaction enabled.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thank you! I think I've made some mistake before because I tried this option but my animation became really strange and I made in other way.

Comment: There might  be option to be passed `AllowUserInteraction`. I know that is in Obj C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the animation option UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay:, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: , completion: )
```

Answer (score 0):

The final code works fine and looks like:

```
 var max: Bool = true

      func startAnimation() {

        max = !max
        let duration: Double = 1
        let fullCircle = 2 * M_PI


        let upOrDown = (max ? CGFloat(-1 / 16 * fullCircle) : CGFloat(1 / 16 * fullCircle))
        let scale: (CGFloat, CGFloat) = (max ? (1.0, 1.0) : (1.3, 1.3))


        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { () -> Void in

          let rotationAnimation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(upOrDown)
          let scaleAnimation = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale)
          self.startButton.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotationAnimation, scaleAnimation)

          }) { (finished) -> Void in

             self.startAnimation()

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` the following might also help you

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .easeInOut) {
    // animation code
}
animator.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
animator.startAnimation()
```